# How to convert StartDate and EndDate to DateTimeZone in Event Audit .Net?

Tags: audit.net

{
"EventType": "Order:Update",
"Environment": {
"UserName": "Federico",
"MachineName": "HP",
"DomainName": "HP",
"CallingMethodName": "Audit.UnitTest.AuditTests.TestUpdate()",
"Exception": null,
"Culture": "en-GB"
},
"Target": {
"Type": "Order",
"Old": {
"OrderId": "39dc0d86-d5fc-4d2e-b918-fb1a97710c99",
"Status": 2,

```
    },
    "New": {
        "OrderId": "39dc0d86-d5fc-4d2e-b918-fb1a97710c99",
        "Status": -1,
        
    }
},
"ReferenceId": "39dc0d86-d5fc-4d2e-b918-fb1a97710c99",           // <-- Custom Field
"Comments": ["Status Updated to Cancelled"],                     // <-- Comments
"StartDate": "2016-08-23T11:34:44.656101-05:00",
"EndDate": "2016-08-23T11:34:55.1810821-05:00",
"Duration": 8531
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the type of the `AuditEvent` properties, but you can add [custom fields](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-fields-and-comments) to the audit event with [custom actions](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions).

For example:

```cs
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnScopeCreated, scope =>
{
    scope.SetCustomField("StartDateTimeZone", GetCurrentDate());
});

Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnEventSaving, scope =>
{
    scope.SetCustomField("EndDateTimeZone", GetCurrentDate());
});
```